# When rendering (4090x2900 px), my cloth has bad geometry

Tags: rendering, geometry

let me put the image first.[image]

The problem I got is that my cloth has a bad geometry when rendering (It's the object vertical in the center of the render that is overlapping other objects.), but in 3D view (Not rendering) it has a good geometry.

I don't know if it only happens when rendering 4090x2900 px (100%). I haven't tried with a low px render, but I think it won't be a problem.

Also, I have checked the correct frame, it's the frame 77 that I want to render.

Thank for the answer, this is my first 4090x2900 px, so I don't know if it's a problem because of that.

Also, the camera covers all the body of the character, but here the render only shows a part of the body, I don't know why.

Comment: Could you provide a screen of your mesh?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I found out that the problem was  that subsurface modifier was 1 and it should be 2 (for render).